# UDF - How to turn a string that contains a path, workbook name, worksheet name and cell reference into a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a UDF that will turn a string that contains path, workbook name, worksheet name and a cell reference into a formula so I can easily return values from other workbooks. For example, my string looks like:

```
='C:\FolderAlfa\SubfolderBeta\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2'!$D$4
```

I tried `Application.Evaluate(string)` and `ExecuteExcel4Macro(string)` methods but none of them are working.

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Do you mean sth like that `Range("A1").Formula = "='C:\FolderAlfa\SubfolderBeta\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2'!$D$4"`?

Comment: Not sure why you want a UDF ... you could always use the evil INDIRECT function in a formula instead.

Note that none of these methods work when the external workbook is closed

Comment: Yes, but I would like this to be an UDF so I'm not sure how to use the Range object since it requires a reference (like "A1")

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. The Evaluate method works perfectly when the other workbooks is open but I'm looking for a solution that would work if the other workbook is closed.

Comment: Then the formula I posted should work. It will just add a link to the workbook even if it's closed.

Comment: @Storax: But a UDF cannot insert a formula into a range.

Comment: @Charles Williams: Right but I am not saying the OP should use an UDF. If he would like to use an UDF then he will need to go another direction.

Comment: @Storax: I agree with you. But since I'm doing a UDF (not a procedure), what argument should I put in Range() in order to work? For example, I created a UDF whose arguments are path, workbook name, worksheet name and cell. This UDF creates a string of all these arguments. Now I need some method to turn this string into a formula so the actual value would be returned

Comment: @Matthew: I added an answer where an UDF inserts a formula into a worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I found [here](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/how-to-change-another-cell-with-a-vba-function-udf/) it is possible to change cells with an UDF and insert a formula.

It is a little bit cumbersome (maybe there is someone out there who can improve it) but it works. You also need to do a recalculation what you can't trigger from the function getValue and the sub addFormula. You must put it somewhere else. The parameter rg is the cell where you want to put the formula. Make sure is is not the cell where you put getValue.

```
Function getValue(rg As Range, path As String, file As String, sheet As String, ref As String)
    Evaluate "addFormula( " & Chr(34) & rg.Address & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & ref & Chr(34) & ")"
    getValue = ""
End Function

Sub addFormula(trgAddress As String, myFormula As String)
    Dim trgRg As Range

    Set trgRg = Range(trgAddress)
    trgRg.Formula = "=" & myFormula

End Sub
```

In the worksheet selection change I added the calculate method. This is for sure not the best way to do it but it shows it is possible.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Calculate
End Sub
```

And that how you can use it: The function is in D5, the result in E5

[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks excellent! Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome! I learned that it is possible to change with an UDF cells in a worksheet although MS documentation states otherwise.