# My User Defined Function does not return formatted results

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please tell me why this is not working?

```
Function CHECKERROR1(a As Long, b As Long) As Range
    If a = b Then
    Else
        CHECKERROR1.Font.Color = vbRed
        CHECKERROR1.Value = "ERROR"
    End If
End Function
```

I want to return a red 'ERROR' when the two numbers don't match

Comment: A udf can't return a color.

Comment: This is not working because `CHECKERROR1` is `Nothing`, because you never assigned it to a `Range`. If you did assign it to a Range, it would work, unless you [call it from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3622544/11683).

Comment: Normally you can't but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993127/6600940) I learned that it might be possible. So, if you tweak my approach you might be able to do that.

Comment: You can however use conditional formatting.

Comment: @JvDV: Yes, right, that will probably be the right way to go here.