# New function in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

For first of all, this is my first time when try to use `vba` in `excel`. I know nothing about it.

I try to create a new function, into `excel`, to set a value in a specific cell.

I have this module:

```
Public Function SETVALUE(cell As Range, newValue As Integer) As String

    cell.value = newValue

    SETVALUE = "-"

End Function
```

This is my module:

[image]

If I type: `=SETVALUE(A2, 1)` in cell `A1`, it not work.

In cell `A1` appear `#Value!` and in cell `A2` appear nothing.

Comment: A function called by the worksheet cannot modify the value of another cell.

Comment: I would say it's probably not a good idea to do it but it's possible, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990057/udf-how-to-turn-a-string-that-contains-a-path-workbook-name-worksheet-name-a/55993127#55993127)

Comment: @ScottCraner so, I can't achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SETVALUE(cell As Range, newValue As Integer) As String

    Evaluate "mySetValue( " & Chr(34) & cell.Address & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & newValue & Chr(34) & ")"
    SETVALUE = "-"

End Function


Sub mySetValue(cell As String, newValue As Integer)
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range(cell)
    rg.Value2 = newValue
End Sub
```

**Update:** Image how to use it

[image]

Comment: The formula you typed contains an error: `=SETVALUE(A2, 1)`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I type that formula into `A1` and hit enter and get that error: `The formula you typed contains an error`. Also, in module, after type `Range` it change into `range`

Comment: My mistake I put `,` at `A2, 1`. It need to be `;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See here [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel) that says:

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot
>   change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a
>   function cannot do any of the following: Insert, delete, or format
>   cells on the spreadsheet. **Change another cell's value**.

The solution is to pass by a sub-routine
Like this

```
Public Function SETVALUE(cell As Range, newValue As Integer) As String

Dim updateCell As String

SETVALUE = "-"

updateCell = "updateRange(" & cell.Address(False, False) & "," & newValue & ")"
Evaluate (updateCell)

End Function

Sub updateRange(vCell As Range, vNewValue As Integer)

vCell = vNewValue

End Sub
```